# How to write conditional operators using JSP expression tags

Tags: java, jsp

I have tried to write conditional operator logic in jsp expression xml tag using "cdata". but it generates an error. even tried with the (<) but not resoloved

Ex:  10 < 15

can any body have the solution for this? Please help me on this.

Comment: You should add the generated error and what you have tried.

Comment: yes tried for the same....but not working..

Comment: can you put the code and the generated error here ? We can't say anything without seeing your code

Comment: While using &lt; it showing syntatical error as ";". and i found solution for this. use <%= 10 [cdata[!---etc %>. but i'm not sure about the XML expression(<jsp-expression> ? </jsp-expression> tag.